# Setting negative DEM values for the sea and water bodies to zero

Tags: gdal, dem, wgs84, bhuvan, egm2008

I've downloaded a few of the Cartosat-1 CartoDEM Version-3 R1 files from BHUVAN (https://bhuvan-app3.nrsc.gov.in/data/download/index.php).

The files seem to be in the WGS84 format and have values of -255 for the sea and other bodies of water.
If I convert the DEM files to the EGM2008 model, the values that have been -255 are still negative (which makes sense, since I think the converter just adds the geoid height to those values).

It seems as if these negative values (after the conversion) only appear for the sea, other bodies of water and pixels very close to them.
When I compare the coordinates with the negative values from my EGM08 converted file with Google Earth or any other coordinate to elevation site, the elevation is 0 for the same coordinates on these sites.

Is it reasonable to just set all these negative values to 0 to get an accurate EGM2008 DEM file or is some other method suggested?